# A world of truth tellers and liars. How did it come about?

Tags: science-based, society, culture

**Please see edit made to avoid closure due to opinion.**

There is a genre of logic puzzles whose solution depends on truth tellers and liars, e.g.

> A princess visits an island inhabited by two tribes. Members of one
> tribe always tell the truth, and members of the other tribe always
> lie.
>
> The princess comes to a fork in the road. She needs to know which road
> leads to the castle so as to avoid the fire-breathing dragon and
> rescue the prince from the wizard holding him captive in the castle.
> (Although the princess doesn't know it, the south road leads to the
> castle and the north road leads to the dragon.)
>
> Standing at this fork in the road is a member of each tribe, but the
> princess can't tell which tribe each belongs to. What question should
> she ask to find the road to the castle?
> [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20180101031058/http://mathforum.org/dr.math/faq/faq.liar.html)

Let us suppose this island exists. What plausible explanation, **based on studies of anthropology**, can account for the tribal split?

**Questions**

**1.** How did this come about? Why does one tribe always tell the truth? Why does the other tribe always lie?

What momentous events in the history of the island caused this split.

**2.**  How does the split affect daily life and how does it affect trade between the tribes?

**3.** What should the child of a mixed marriage between truthers and liars do? Should they lie or tell the truth?

**EDIT**

There are some close-votes on account of the answers being said to be a matter of opinion. I will therefore change the question to ask for scientific backup of  answers. Are there any anthropologists who can comment on the validity of existing answers or give answers based on knowledge of actual studies that have been made of tribal interactions? Are there any cases of tribes that have a similar cultural split? Do they coexist in peace or are they constantly warring with each other?

Comment: One point of clarity for me: Does the lying tribe always tell lies to *everyone* (even their own tribe mates) or do they only tell lies to those not of their tribe? Maybe this really doesn't matter WRT your questions, but seems pertinent to me, especially when considering questions 2 and 3.

Comment: @Paulster2, It is a good question. Going by the way the  puzzles are usually written I think I have to say that they always tell lies no matter who they speak to. In the puzzles they mostly lie in response to Yes/No questions. I'll say that they never tell the truth under any circumstances (and they cannot use hand-signals or other methods to indicate the truth).

Comment: I voted to close as opinion-based, when I should have voted to close as Too Broad. This is Idea Generation. Also, a suggestion: Weave the information from the edit into the question. That way, it makes the question stronger, and will make anyone reading it less inclined to vote to close.

Comment: It is a terrible question. There is no such thing as a person who reliably lies so that you may safely presume the opposite. Lying is rather saying something so that the hearer would be more inclined to believe an untruth. And so those who can't solve the logic puzzle may well be more advanced than those who can.

Answer (score 6):

You can explain anything with religion.

A cult developes that takes it as a divine directive to hang out beyond the village limits and talk to strangers. An originally adaptive advantageous idea to confuse enimies, prevent outsiders from gaining useful intelligence about the layout and logistics of the community, generations later became missionaries who sew as much misinformation as they can. Without a complex plan or much intelligence on the part of the members, it's become a matter of lying as much as possible.

Naturally the chamber of commerce, local university, etc. find this outdated and counterproductive in this time of peace and prosperity,  or at least find it ignorant and disgusting what the cult has devolved into. They post helpful citizens around the border to *help* strangers.

Once upon a time the lier offered the kingdom  a competitive advantage, so their existence makes sense. But the situation has changed and the behavior has changed as well, so it doesn't make sense without knowledge of the history.  That history may be initially secret and filled with misinformation itself.

Answer (score 1):

1. In the beginning there was a word. The tribes believe that there is magical power left over from the gods and the creation in words. Speech is sacred ritual of profound power to change reality. Specifically your words should be pure, either entirely true or entirely false. Mixing the two carelessly distorts the connection between your soul and the divine and opens you up for the ever vigilant demons that seek to corrupt the souls of mortals. Pure words on the other hand leave no opening for demons to enter, no clutter for them to hide. But only speaking the truth or falsehood would leave your soul unbalanced and immature thus every year on the darkest night of the year the tribes switch which speaks true and which speaks false. This explains why it is hard to tell which tribe is which. Realistically such belief would be associated in a dualist system along the lines of yin and yang.
2. The locals know which tribe the people they talk with belong to. And since everyone has been in the always lies tribe half their life, everyone is very good in making and understanding communication by negation. Thus this is not a significant hardship for the locals. Trade and interaction with outsiders will be by mixed groups for convenience.
3. When a couple marries and they are of different tribes, one of them changes tribes so that they are of the same tribe. Their child will then be of that common tribe. That is how it usually works and I see no reason why the usual solution would not work here. After all we are not talking about a genetic compulsion?

Comment: I like this. Nicely thought out and actually quite plausible. I like the achieving of balance by alternating truth and lies. Real tribes have done weirder things. Also it's possible that in the past they used to alternate but the polarisation has ended up being permanent  and they just do one or the other. For mixed-marriages there could be a rule that one particular gender has to change. If there was no alternation though, it would be a difficult transition to change the habits of a lifetime.  Food for thought here. Thanks.